# What is $H_1(A_\mathbb{C}^{top},\mathbb{Q})$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, abelian-varieties

Let $A$ be an abelian variety defined over a number field. I have seen in a few papers the singular homology $H_1(A_\mathbb{C}^{top},\mathbb{Q})$ being used. I read up on the singular homology but it hasn't shed any light as to what this specific object is and why it is interesting.

If $V_\ell(A)$ is the rational $\ell$-adic Tate module of $A$, then we get

$$V_\ell(A) \cong H_1(A_\mathbb{C}^{top},\mathbb{Q}) \otimes \mathbb{Q}_\ell$$

To me this seems like it would be related to the (non-rational) $\ell$-adic Tate module $T_\ell(A)$. However, it clearly won't be the same as $T_l(A)$ will be a $\mathbb{Z}_\ell$-mdoule and $H_1(A_\mathbb{C}^{top},\mathbb{Q})$ will be a $\mathbb{Q}$-module.

So my question is: what exactly is $H_1(A_\mathbb{C}^{top},\mathbb{Q})$ and why is it important? Am I correct in that it is related to $T_\ell(A)$?

Comment: Well, if $A$ is an $n$-dimensional abelian variety, then $H_1 (A, \mathbb{Q})$ is a $2 n$-dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. But I suppose you have worked that out already.

Comment: "hasn't shed any light as to what this specific object is" - I read this as saying you can't find the definition of the first singular homology group of a topological space. If that's the case, see [Hatcher](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html). But I have a feeling that I am misunderstanding what you mean.

Comment: Also, an example of such a paper would probably help.